# actingAs doesn't work as expected for feature testing. laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I actually am not able to understand why I am getting the following error.

```
App\Models\User::team must return a relationship instance, but "null" was returned. Was the "return" keyword used?
```

I am basically creating test cases for simple orders for ecommerce.

**User Modal**

```
public function team(): BelongsTo|null
    {
        if (!empty($this->team_id)) {
            return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Test case**

```
public function test_order_status_update()
    {
        $order = $this->create_order($this->books->id, $this->appUser->id, $this->address->id);
        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->put('orders/' . $order->json('order.id'), [
            'order_status' => 'ordered',
        ]);
        $response->assertRedirect('orders/' . $order->json('order.id'))->assertSessionHas('success');
    }
```

In addition, I have another feature in my application called pages access control, which controls page access for multiple users (admin, developer, and users).
I have implemented this feature manually using middleware.

**Middlware.php**

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        //teams 1-Developer 2-Admin 3-Management 4-Marketing 5-Audit 6-Sales 7-Bookstores 8-Delivery 9-User
        $team = $request->user()->team;
        if ($team->id == 1 || $team->id == 2) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        $pages =  auth()->user()->pages->merge(auth()->user()->team->pages);
        $currentRouteName = $request->route()->getName();
        $pages->contains('route_name', $currentRouteName) ?: abort(403);
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Based on the error above, I believe the **actingAs** function is unable to obtain authenticated user information, which is why my test failed.
How can I fix this?

Comment: As @Yinci already mentioned, you don't have to check if you have `team_id` or not, you just share the relationship, and whenever you want to get something back, you just do `$model->team`, it can be `null` or `Team`, but you must always return a relationship

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't check your `team_id`:

```php
public function team(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}
```

Laravel tries to be smart. If `team_id` isn't set, it will just return `null`. However, if you don't return the `BelongsTo`, the magic code of Laravel will trip when you try to access `user->team`